# How do I render .NET TableCell as TH instead of TD?

Tags: .net

I'm dynamically building a .NET Table, including TableRows with TablesSection set, resulting in 1 THEAD row and multiple TBODY rows.  Now I need to get the TableCells in the THEAD row to render with TH tags rather than TD tags.  How do I do that?  I haven't found a TableCell attribute for that, and it won let me add Literals to the row Cells collection.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you tried [`TableHeaderCell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tableheadercell.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HtmlGenericControl th = new HtmlGenericControl("th")` and add that to the thead row.

Comment: How do I add it to the row?  Using row.Cells.Add(mycell) gives a compile-time error, and row.Controls.Add(mycell) gives a run-time error.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to inherit the `TableCell` class and overwrite the `Render` method.

This gives you the ability to truly customize your WebControl as well as add additional methods that may benefit your particular scenario.

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        if (Type == CellType.th)
        {
            writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagLeftChar + "th"); // Render <th
            Attributes.Render(writer); // Render any associated attributes
            writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar); // Render >
            base.RenderContents(writer); // Render the content between the <th></th> tags
            writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.EndTagLeftChars + "th" + HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar); // Render </th>
        }
        else
            base.Render(writer); // Defaults to rendering <td>
    }
```

This solution allows you to inherit from one class as opposed to both `TableCell` and `TableHeaderCell` in the event you wish to customize them respectively.

**EDIT**

The `Type` property in the `if` statement is a custom property of the class, in which I've added an `enum` to simplify the applicable types.

```
public enum CellType
{
    td,
    th
}

private CellType _Type;
public CellType Type
{
    get { return _Type; }
    set { _Type = value; }
}
```